# MAX7219 and Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, led, max7219

I am getting started in running this 8x8 led on an Arduino. Regardless of which tutorial sketch I attempted, I never got a scrolling text that I expect. What happens seems to be only a single (out of four) led module being addressed at a time, resulting in, for example, the message being scrolled on one module at a time, but all four in succession. Could it be a module problem?

Answer (score 1):

Got it somewhat working by changing:

```
#define HARDWARE_TYPE MD_MAX72XX::FC16_HW
to: 
#define HARDWARE_TYPE MD_MAX72XX::ICSTATION_HW
But still a little problem with the last character in a message not showing all leds lit until it starts to scroll after the initial program delay. Then all is fine.
Anyone want to address that issue? My sketch follows:

{    // Use the Parola library to scroll text on the display
//
// Demonstrates the use of the scrolling function to display text received
// from the serial interface
//
// User can enter text on the serial monitor and this will display as a
// scrolling message on the display.
// Speed for the display is controlled by a pot on SPEED_IN analog in.
// Scrolling direction is controlled by a switch on DIRECTION_SET digital in.
// Invert ON/OFF is set by a switch on INVERT_SET digital in.
//
// UISwitch library can be found at https://github.com/MajicDesigns/MD_UISwitch
// MD_MAX72XX library can be found at https://github.com/MajicDesigns/MD_MAX72XX
//

#include <MD_Parola.h>
#include <MD_MAX72xx.h>
#include <SPI.h>

// set to 1 if we are implementing the user interface pot, switch, etc
#define USE_UI_CONTROL 0

#if USE_UI_CONTROL
#include <MD_UISwitch.h>
#endif

// Turn on debug statements to the serial output
#define DEBUG 0

#if DEBUG
#define PRINT(s, x) { Serial.print(F(s)); Serial.print(x); }
#define PRINTS(x) Serial.print(F(x))
#define PRINTX(x) Serial.println(x, HEX)
#else
#define PRINT(s, x)
#define PRINTS(x)
#define PRINTX(x)
#endif

// Define the number of devices we have in the chain and the hardware interface
// NOTE: These pin numbers will probably not work with your hardware and may
// need to be adapted
//#define HARDWARE_TYPE MD_MAX72XX::FC16_HW
//#define HARDWARE_TYPE MD_MAX72XX::GENERIC_HW
#define HARDWARE_TYPE MD_MAX72XX::ICSTATION_HW
#define MAX_DEVICES 4
#define CLK_PIN   13
#define DATA_PIN  11
#define CS_PIN    10

// HARDWARE SPI
MD_Parola P = MD_Parola(HARDWARE_TYPE, CS_PIN, MAX_DEVICES);
// SOFTWARE SPI
//MD_Parola P = MD_Parola(HARDWARE_TYPE, DATA_PIN, CLK_PIN, CS_PIN, MAX_DEVICES);

// Scrolling parameters
#if USE_UI_CONTROL
const uint8_t SPEED_IN = A5;
const uint8_t DIRECTION_SET = 8;  // change the effect
const uint8_t INVERT_SET = 9;     // change the invert

const uint8_t SPEED_DEADBAND = 5;
#endif // USE_UI_CONTROL

uint8_t scrollSpeed = 25;    // default frame delay value
textEffect_t scrollEffect = PA_SCROLL_LEFT;
textPosition_t scrollAlign = PA_LEFT;
uint16_t scrollPause = 2000; // in milliseconds

// Global message buffers shared by Serial and Scrolling functions
#define BUF_SIZE    75
char curMessage[BUF_SIZE] = { "" };
char newMessage[BUF_SIZE] = { "Got Signals?" };//{ "Hello! Enter new message?" };
bool newMessageAvailable = true;

#if USE_UI_CONTROL

MD_UISwitch_Digital uiDirection(DIRECTION_SET);
MD_UISwitch_Digital uiInvert(INVERT_SET);

void doUI(void)
{
  // set the speed if it has changed
  {
    int16_t speed = map(analogRead(SPEED_IN), 0, 1023, 10, 150);

    if ((speed >= ((int16_t)P.getSpeed() + SPEED_DEADBAND)) ||
      (speed <= ((int16_t)P.getSpeed() - SPEED_DEADBAND)))
    {
      P.setSpeed(speed);
      scrollSpeed = speed;
      PRINT("\nChanged speed to ", P.getSpeed());
    }
  }

  if (uiDirection.read() == MD_UISwitch::KEY_PRESS) // SCROLL DIRECTION
  {
    PRINTS("\nChanging scroll direction");
    scrollEffect = (scrollEffect == PA_SCROLL_LEFT ? PA_SCROLL_RIGHT : PA_SCROLL_LEFT);
    P.setTextEffect(scrollEffect, scrollEffect);
    P.displayClear();
    P.displayReset();
  }

  if (uiInvert.read() == MD_UISwitch::KEY_PRESS)  // INVERT MODE
  {
    PRINTS("\nChanging invert mode");
    P.setInvert(!P.getInvert());
  }
}
#endif // USE_UI_CONTROL

void readSerial(void)
{
  static char *cp = newMessage;

  while (Serial.available())
  {
    *cp = (char)Serial.read();
    if ((*cp == '\n') || (cp - newMessage >= BUF_SIZE-2)) // end of message character or full buffer
    {
      *cp = '\0'; // end the string
      // restart the index for next filling spree and flag we have a message waiting
      cp = newMessage;
      newMessageAvailable = true;
    }
    else  // move char pointer to next position
      cp++;
  }
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(57600);
  Serial.print("\n[Parola Scrolling Display]\nType a message for the scrolling display\nEnd message line with a newline");

#if USE_UI_CONTROL
  uiDirection.begin();
  uiInvert.begin();
  pinMode(SPEED_IN, INPUT);

  doUI();
#endif // USE_UI_CONTROL

  P.begin();
  P.displayText(curMessage, scrollAlign, scrollSpeed, scrollPause, scrollEffect, scrollEffect);
}

void loop()
{
#if USE_UI_CONTROL
  doUI();
#endif // USE_UI_CONTROL

  if (P.displayAnimate())
  {
    if (newMessageAvailable)
    {
      strcpy(curMessage, newMessage);
      newMessageAvailable = false;
    }
    P.displayReset();
  }
  readSerial();
}
```

}

Comment: I suggested an edit to format the code but is this your final answer to the question? If this code still has problems you might be best adding a description of what's wrong and editing it into your question instead.

Comment: "Somewhat working?"

Comment: Yes, the change to ICSTATION corrected the problem. Thanks for your interest.